# Not able to use packages instaled with npm

Tags: macos, npm

I am installing a package using the command `npm install -g` and the package is installed successfully. But I am not able to use that package from terminal. For example: `npm install -g create-react-app` and then when I run create-react-app it says `zsh: command not found: create-react-app`.

I reinstalled node and npm and after that this problem is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `npx` instead. It comes with `npm` 5.2 or greater. You can read more about this in the [`react` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app).

To summarize, just run the following:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Comment: The problem here is not react specific. It is happening for every package. I am not able to use the package after installing it with npm.